# Building dynamic array using javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript

I want to create dynamic array from server data,

For example,

I need format in the following way:

```
["project1","project2","project3"]
```

This is my code

```
var arrayVal = [];
    for(var i=0;i<project.name;i++){
      //array generation
    }
```

project1,project2,.... are getting from server.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `JSON.parse`. Here's an example copied form the JS terminal.

```
> a = JSON.parse('["project1","project2","project3"]')
["project1", "project2", "project3"]
> a[0]
"project1"
```

Now, be weary, JSON isn't integrated to all browsers yet. You can download a JSON script to emulate the native functions. See [here](http://www.json.org/js.html) and [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)